# Xdebug doesn't work with Docker + VSCode + Linux

Tags: php, linux, docker, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I've tested all the settings I've found on the internet, but I haven't been successful in setting up my Xdebug to run with my Docker. It's active but I can't use the breakpoint; it's as if it's not receiving the connection I'm establishing. My settings are:

**php.ini**

```ini
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=develop,coverage,debug,profile
xdebug.log = /home/rafael/Desktop/sistemas/legado/web_server/logs/xdebug.log
xdebug.idekey=docker
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.log_level=0
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.discover_client_host=true
```

**launch.json**

```json
{
 "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "hostname": "0.0.0.0",
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www": "${workspaceFolder}"
              },
            "log": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9003,
            "log": true
        }
    ]
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./web_server/Dockerfile.devLocal
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    container_name: legado_web
    depends_on: 
      - php_app
    ports:
      - 90:90
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      ######################################################
      # Atenção!
      # Caso esteja utilizando MacOS, comente o volume:
      #   - ./sistemas:/home/cover/ambiente/sistemas/
      ######################################################
      - ./sistemas:/home/cover/ambiente/sistemas/
      - ./web_server/logs:/var/log/nginx/
      - ./storage:/home/storage
      - ./etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini:/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
      - /home/rafael/Desktop/sistemas/legado/web_server/logs:/path/inside/container
      - /home/rafael/Desktop/sistemas/legado/web_server/logs:/var/logs
  php_app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.devLocal
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    container_name: legado_php_app
    env_file:
      - ./env/local/geral.env
      - ./env/local/firefly.env
    environment:
      - APPLICATION_ENV=docker-devlocal
    volumes:
      ######################################################
      # Atenção!
      # Caso esteja utilizando MacOS, comente o volume:
      #   - ./sistemas:/home/cover/ambiente/sistemas/
      ######################################################
      - ./sistemas:/home/cover/ambiente/sistemas/
      # Inserir caminho para .ssh na máquina local
      # - /home/ditic/.ssh:/root/.ssh
      - ./config/php-devLocal.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ./storage:/home/storage
      - /home/rafael/Desktop/sistemas/legado/web_server/logs:/path/inside/container
      - /home/rafael/Desktop/sistemas/legado/web_server/logs:/var/logs
      - ./etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini:/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

WORKDIR /home/cover/ambiente/sistemas/

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y ssh

# driver postgres
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libpq-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql

# GD
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg && \
    docker-php-ext-install gd

# LDAP
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y ldap-utils libldap2-dev \
    && ln -fs /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so /usr/lib/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install ldap

# SOAP
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libxml2-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install soap

ENV TZ=America/Sao_Paulo

# TIMEZONEDB
ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync && \
    install-php-extensions timezonedb

# IMAGICK
RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends && \
    pecl -vvv install imagick && docker-php-ext-enable imagick && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#ZIP_ARCHIVE
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    libzip-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip

# SOLR
RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y libcurl4-gnutls-dev && \
    printf "\n" | pear install pecl/solr

# EXCEL do WEBTAF
RUN pear install OLE-1.0.0RC3 && pear install Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer-0.9.4

RUN ls

# CALENDAR
RUN docker-php-ext-install calendar && docker-php-ext-configure calendar

# MBSTRING
RUN apt-get install -y \
    libonig-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install mbstring

# EXIFTOOL
RUN apt update && \
    apt-get -y install exiftool && \
    docker-php-ext-configure exif && \
    docker-php-ext-install exif && \
    docker-php-ext-enable exif

COPY ./config/symlinks.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/symlinks.sh
RUN chmod 0777 /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/symlinks.sh

# #XDEBUG
# RUN pecl install -o -f xdebug-2.9.8 && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

RUN pecl install -o -f xdebug-3.1.6 && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug


# configuração php
# COPY ./config/php.ini $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini
COPY ./config/php-fpm-devLocal.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/symlinks.sh"]
```

I've tried various IP settings in `xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal`, and have experimented with multiple IP addresses.

Comment: Set `xdebug.log_level=10` and show what's in the log. Also, try debugging a page with `xdebug_info()` in it, and it will tell you what it tried (if anything at all) in the `Diagnostics` section.

Comment: Do you need to export port 9003 from the container, as xdebug is configured to use that port?

Comment: @RichardCross *"Do you need to export port 9003 from the container"* Nope. It's Xdebug that connects to the client (VSCode in this case) and NOT other way around. Exposing port does the opposite: lets Docker to listen on the outside and forward it into the container. If it happens then VSCode will not be able to listen on that port (since it will be used by Docker).